# Input Keyevent in fastboot mode?

Tags: adb, fastboot, bootloader

I'm trying to unlock the bootloader of my old Alcatel OneTouch Idol X+. I got to the point where my phone would ask me to press volume-up to confirm that. Due to a bug of which i read several times now, the volume-up key won't work now.

I tried using that adb input keyevent command, which wouldn't work in fastboot mode. Are there other options, or some way to use adb commands in fastboot mode?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no `adb` command works in Fastboot mode (or bootloader). The only way to communicate with a device in Fastboot mode is `fastboot`.

In your case, you should try finding a replacement key for the non-working one, or you're out of luck.